# Iterate through GMap.net Route Items

Tags: c#

I'm using [GMap.net](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/documentation) to get google maps directions.

I'm using the code like the following and I have an array of Points which is perfect. However, I want to loop through the results for soemthing else, but I can't seem to grab them.

```
PointLatLng start = new PointLatLng(-25.974134, 32.593042);
PointLatLng end = new PointLatLng(-25.959048, 32.592827);
MapRoute route = GMap.NET.MapProviders.GoogleMapProvider.Instance.GetRoute(
    start, end, false, false, 15);
List<String> myP = route.Points;
```

I get the error:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<GMap.NET.PointLatLng>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'
```

Comment: You are trying to convert `List<GMap.NET.PointLatLng>` into `List<string>` which is not going to work.

Comment: Do you know how i can get it to a format I can loop through

Comment: Hopefully my answer solves your problem, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to convert `List<GMap.NET.PointLatLng>` into `List<string>`.

If you want to iterate through them as the post title suggests, remove the last line and replace with:

```
foreach(var point in route.Points)
{
    //Now point is a GMap.NET.PointLatLng object
    ...
}
```